# How can I check if a file is selected using t:inputFileUpload before submitting/uploading

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, tomahawk

I wanted to know if it is possible to check if a file is already selected prior to a click on submit/upload button?

The problem I want to solve with this option is to hide the "submit/upload" button if no file has already selected? Using `required="true"` attribute is not an option for me because the user doesn't always have to provide a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by initially hiding the upload button by CSS and attaching some JS to the `change` event of the file field which displays the upload button if a file has been selected.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{bean.file}" required="true" 
        onchange="document.getElementById('form:upload').style.display = (!!value) ? 'block' : 'none'" />
    <h:commandButton id="upload" value="Upload" action="#{bean.upload}" style="display: none;" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. What you suggested is a good idea but onblur happens only when the user clicks on somewhere else than the browse button. The user is thus not aware of what he/she should do when the file has selected until he/she accidentally clicks on something else, and sees the submit button is shown. 

Also even if the user doesn't select a file the submit button will appear which he/she can click on the submit button while no file has selected and thus I get some errors regarding the bean.file.

Does jsf provides nothing to check the content of a component or something?

Comment: @BalusC How can I do something similar but for disabling/enabling command button?